# Не загружается ссылка из сборки на сборку из ресурсов

Tags: c#, assembly

Извиняюсь за туфтологию, но в общем то проблема примерно так и выглядит...

Есть приложение, которое ссылается на 3 сборки (назовём их `Assembly1, Assembly2, Assembly3` оформлены как "библиотека классов") все они также встроены в главное приложение как embedded resource и подгружаются при запуске через `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += {...}`.

Всё было хорошо, до тех пор, пока `Assembly3` не стала ссылаться на `Assembly2`. После этого главное приложение перестало запускаться если не подкинуть вручную `Assembly2` в основной каталог. (вылетает *APPCRASH* с *KERNELBASE.dll*)

UPD:

В общем то удалось решить таким образом, хоть самой сути вроде и не решает.
Главная точка входа программы выглядела примерно таким образом:

```
...
using Assembly2;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(ResolveEventHandler);

            Assembly2.Method1();

            ...
    }
```

Проблема ушла после того `Assembly2.Method1()` перенёс из точки входа в код инициализации главной формы приложения...

Answer (score 1):

Была у меня такая же ситуация. Так ничего и не смог сделать. Лучше всего переработать код, избавившись от таких сложных и циклических ссылок. А то еще неизвестно, как это аукнется...